# python get length of the positional arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am learning how to use positional and optional arguments.
My input:

```
$ python generate_data.py output --spt google.spt OK-Google.spt --fpx google.fpx OK-Google.fpx
```

Code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate an output file from the contents of *.spt and *.fpx.')
parser.add_argument('output_file') # Number of output files should be 1.
parser.add_argument('--spt', required=True, nargs='+', help='spt files') # Number of *.spt should be >= 1.
parser.add_argument('--fpx', required=True, nargs='+', help='fpx files') # Number of *.fpx should be >= 1.
args = parser.parse_args()

print(len(args.output_file), len(args.spt), len(args.fpx))
if len(args.output_file) != 1 or len(args.spt) != len(args.fpx):
    parser.print_help()
    exit(-1)
```

`output` is the output file of `generate_data.py`, and the number of output file should be 1.
`--spt` are necessary arguments followed by *.spt, whose number should be `>= 1`.
`--fpx` are necessary arguments followed by *.fpx, whose number should be `>= 1`.

My question are the following:
1. I got `len(args.output_file) == 6`, but not 1. How do I make sure users enter only one output file?
2. I want output file could also be placed in the end of the command line like the following.

```
 $ python generate_data.py --spt google.spt OK-Google.spt --fpx google.fpx OK-Google.fpx output
```

Comment: During debugging I like to `print(args)`.  That way I see the parsing results without expectations.  In this case it would show what `otuput_file` is a string, not a list. 2) Ideally `argparse` should recognize that it needs to reserve one string the remaining positional, but that enhancement is still waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's already done.  Try it: the script will not accept two filenames.  You are getting confused because args.output_file is a string.  In your case you entered a filename with a length of 6, which explains why len(args.output_file) is 6.  The other variables args.spt and args.fpx are *lists* because you defined those arguments with the `nargs` keyword.  So len(args.spt) returns how many items are in the list.
2. This doesn't make much sense.  Since --fpx and --spt take more than one filename, you have no way of telling whether a filename that comes at the end of the command line belongs to the last list or is the name of the output file.  If you want to solve this problem by using file name extensions to figure out how many files of which type have been entered, then you might as well accept free-form input of a list of filenames and get rid of the argparse stuff entirely.